# Problem related to successive differentiation

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, derivatives

> If $y = x^{n-1}\log x$ then prove that $y_n=\dfrac{(n-1)!}{x}$

I do this a little bit which is

$y_n=(n-1)D^{n-1}(x^{n-2}\log x)$ , I eliminate the term $D^{n-1}(x^{n-2})$ as it equals to $0$

but I do not understand how to proceed further....

Comment: Set $u(x)=x^{n-1}$ and $v(x)=\log x$ so that $y=u\cdot v$.  Then you can apply the chain rule: at the moment you've only calculated one half of the product; the other half should help you see what to do next

Answer (score 2):

Express it as $xy=x^n \ln{x}$. Then:

$$1) \ y+xy'=nx^{n-1}\ln{x}+x^{n-1}=ny+x^{n-1}\Rightarrow xy'=(n-1)y+x^{n-1}$$
$$2) \ y'+xy''=(n-1)y'+(n-1)x^{n-2}\Rightarrow xy''=(n-2)y'+(n-1)x^{n-2}$$
$$3) \ y''+xy'''=(n-2)y''+(n-1)(n-2)x^{n-3}\Rightarrow xy'''=(n-3)y''+(n-1)(n-2)x^{n-3}$$
$$...$$
$$n) \ y^{(n-1)}+xy^{(n)}=y^{(n-1)}+(n-1)!\Rightarrow y^{(n)}=\frac{(n-1)!}{x}$$

Answer (score 1):

(I replace $n-1$ by $n$.)

Let
$$f_n(x):=x^n\log x\qquad(n\geq0)\ .$$
Then $Df_n(x)=n x^{n-1}\log x+x^{n-1}$, or
$$Df_n(x)=nf_{n-1}(x)+p_{n-1}(x)\ ,$$
whereby   $p_r(x)$, $r\in{\mathbb N}_{\geq0}$, denotes some polynomial of degree $\leq r$. Proceeding inductively we obtain
$$D^nf_n(x)=n! f_0(x)+p_0(x)\ ,$$
hence $D^{n+1}f_n(x)={\displaystyle{n!\over x}}$, as claimed.